# R add lines to plot

Tags: r, plot

I have my code its generally do what I want:

```
V_max=10
V_min=0
x_lim_min=-1
x_lim_max=13


base_plot_fun <- function(x, x1, y, y1) {
  mean_x <- mean(x)
  mean_x1 <- mean(x1)
  
  # initialize the plot
  plot(
    0,
    0,
    ylim = range(c(y$counts, y1$counts)),
    xlim = range(c(y$breaks, y1$breaks)),
    xlab = "x",
    ylab = "counts",
    type = "n"
    
  )
  
  
  corners <- par('usr') # get the corners of the plots
  
  x_left <- corners[1]
  x_right <- quantile(x, 0.95) # at 95 percentile, change as needed
  
  x1_left <- x_right
  x1_right <- quantile(x1, 0.05) # at 5th percentile, change if needed
  
  rect(
    xleft = x_left,
    xright = x_right,
    ybottom = corners[3],
    ytop = corners[4],
    col = 'lightblue',
    density = 100
  )
  rect(
    xleft = x1_left,
    xright = x1_right,
    ybottom = corners[3],
    ytop = corners[4],
    col = 'pink',
    density = 100
  )
}

x <- rnorm(100,V_min,1)
x1 <- rnorm(100,V_max,1)
y <- hist(x,plot=FALSE,breaks = 20)
y1 <- hist(x1, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)

base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)
plot(y, col='gray48',add=T,xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))
plot(y1, col='gray48',add=T,xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))
```

I want to put 4 following lines into my code:

```
abline(v=x_right,col='steelblue',lwd=3)
abline(v=x1_right,col='firebrick',lwd=3)
abline(v=mean_x,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
abline(v=mean_x1,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
```

I want these four bars to appear in my charts. I try to insert it in such a way as not to break the current code, but I can't get it right. Therefore, I am asking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you want lines in background

If you just copy and paste those 4 lines and post them right at the end of the function. it seems to work (assumin you want the lines in the background, behind the historgrams).

```
V_max=10
V_min=0
x_lim_min=-1
x_lim_max=13


base_plot_fun <- function(x, x1, y, y1) {
  mean_x <- mean(x)
  mean_x1 <- mean(x1)
  
  # initialize the plot
  plot(
    0,
    0,
    ylim = range(c(y$counts, y1$counts)),
    xlim = range(c(y$breaks, y1$breaks)),
    xlab = "x",
    ylab = "counts",
    type = "n"
    
  )
  
  corners <- par('usr') # get the corners of the plots
  
  x_left <- corners[1]
  x_right <- quantile(x, 0.95) # at 95 percentile, change as needed
  
  x1_left <- x_right
  x1_right <- quantile(x1, 0.05) # at 5th percentile, change if needed
  
  rect(
    xleft = x_left,
    xright = x_right,
    ybottom = corners[3],
    ytop = corners[4],
    col = 'lightblue',
    density = 100
  )
  rect(
    xleft = x1_left,
    xright = x1_right,
    ybottom = corners[3],
    ytop = corners[4],
    col = 'pink',
    density = 100
  )
  #### PUT LINES HERE ####
  abline(v=x_right,col='steelblue',lwd=3) 
  abline(v=x1_right,col='firebrick',lwd=3)
  abline(v=mean_x,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
  abline(v=mean_x1,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
}

x <- rnorm(100,V_min,1)
x1 <- rnorm(100,V_max,1)
y <- hist(x,plot=FALSE,breaks = 20)
y1 <- hist(x1, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)

base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)
plot(y, col='gray48',add=T,xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))
plot(y1, col='gray48',add=T,xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))
```

[image]

### If you want lines in foreground

```
V_max=10
V_min=0
x_lim_min=-1
x_lim_max=13


base_plot_fun <- function(x, x1, y, y1) {
  mean_x <- mean(x)
  mean_x1 <- mean(x1)
  
  # initialize the plot
  plot(
    0,
    0,
    ylim = range(c(y$counts, y1$counts)),
    xlim = range(c(y$breaks, y1$breaks)),
    xlab = "x",
    ylab = "counts",
    type = "n"
    
  )
  
  
  corners <- par('usr') # get the corners of the plots
  
  x_left <- corners[1]
  x_right <- quantile(x, 0.95) # at 95 percentile, change as needed
  
  x1_left <- x_right
  x1_right <- quantile(x1, 0.05) # at 5th percentile, change if needed
  
  rect(
    xleft = x_left,
    xright = x_right,
    ybottom = corners[3],
    ytop = corners[4],
    col = 'lightblue',
    density = 100
  )
  rect(
    xleft = x1_left,
    xright = x1_right,
    ybottom = corners[3],
    ytop = corners[4],
    col = 'pink',
    density = 100
  )
  
  plot(y, col='gray48',add=T,xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))
  plot(y1, col='gray48',add=T,xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max)) 
  
  abline(v=x_right,col='steelblue',lwd=3)
  abline(v=x1_right,col='firebrick',lwd=3)
  abline(v=mean_x,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
  abline(v=mean_x1,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)

}
x <- rnorm(100,V_min,1)
x1 <- rnorm(100,V_max,1)
y <- hist(x,plot=FALSE,breaks = 20)
y1 <- hist(x1, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)

base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. And would you be kind enough to say where I should put code so that the lines are not in the background

Comment: It's all about the ordering. Things later in the code are put on top of things earlier in the code. So if you want the lines on top of the histograms you need to put them afterwards. The problem before was that you put it outside the function so R couldn't find the values you were giving it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show an example of how you can put them in the foreground. Please accept it :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand it means I must put those 4 lines outside of the function?

Comment: See my answer, there's now an example showing you in there.

Comment: Thank you for this change, but when I play the code from your corrected answer, it gets an error: > base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)
Error in mean(x) : object 'x' not found

Comment: Oh, I see, I've fixed that now. (I still had x in my global variable when I moved them, so it worked for me, even though it was wrong). Now it will work :)